# Animating UiView even when the App is in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Is it possible to animate my UiView after an interval to come at the top of a screen even if the app is in background. I have been able to achieve this while the app is in foreground by adding my uiview as a subview to UiWindow. I am running a background thread too which shows that i am coming into that function where my uiview gets added into UiWindow but nothing shows when the app is in background. 
Is there any restriction on iOS level ?

Comment: i think you if want any changes to UI ,do it on main-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple docs: [https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW8](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)

> Avoid updating your windows and views. Because your app’s windows and
>   views are not visible when your app is in the background, you should
>   avoid updating them. The exception is in cases where you need to
>   update the contents of a window prior to having a snapshot of your app
>   taken.